# Is it possible to wait transaction lock release with serializable isolation level?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, jhipster

**Context:**

We've built a JAVA application using **spring framework (5.1.8) & spring boot (2.1.6)** with the help of Jhipster.

It is a RESTFul application.

Data persistance is done in a **PostGRES database managed by Hibernate (5.3.10)**.

**Application constraints:**

Because of our context, we have to process most of update transactions in the same order that they happen.

**Problem:**

All requests are processed by a business function declared as transactionnal (annoted with @Transactionnal(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)).

We set the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE to avoid execution of multiple transaction at the same time (concurrency).

However, with this isolation level, we have to manage the transactions repeat for case of concurrency exception.

Is there a way to force to wait transaction lock release before that isolation throws a concurrency exception (serialize access error), like with pessimistic locks ?

We tried to make transaction synchronized but it doesn't work because it seems commits are done outside the transactions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using postgresql advisory_locks  or maybe Hibernate explicit lock types?

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.
We wouldn't make our code dependant of PostgresSQL, so we can't act at PostgresSQL level.

Comment: What about my other suggestion? Hibernate explicit lock types (not pg specific). Anyway, I tend to consider that being independent from database is a myth that often leads into using sub optimal solutions or more complex ones because you introduce other libraries. You add constraints to your project for a potential migration that could never happen or would require real effort anyway.